# jQuery to modify div background color depending on text contained in another div

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a Wordpress plugin to display events and I want to modify the colors of a background color depending on the text contained in another div.

I have it partially working but it changes the background color of the text div.

I have the code below and I want to modify the background-color of mec-bg-color

HTML

```
<div class="event-grid-t2-head mec-bg-color clearfix">
     <div class="mec-event-month">
        <span class="mec-start-date-label" itemprop="startDate">28 September</span>
        <span class="mec-end-date-label" itemprop="endDate"> - 28 December</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mec-event-detail">
        <div class="mec-event-loc-place">Southern</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  
  $(".mec-bg-color >>.mec-event-loc-place").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var color={'background-color':'#fff'};
    
    switch (text) {
      case "southern":
        color = "#ce1870";
        break;
      case "south eastern":
        color = "#6dc8bf";
        break;
    }
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

The code I have only changes the color for the .mec-event-loc-place element but I would like it to also change the container mec-bg-color.

I think it is close and I know I am missing something simple.

Thanks in advance for any help as I'm still new to jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: You can make it work with your code by using `$(this).closest(".mec-bg-color").css("background-color", color);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be looping through outer div i.e :`.mec-bg-color` and using `.find()` to get required div text and the other way would be using `closest` i.e :  `$(this).closest('.mec-bg-color').css("background-color", color);` .

***Demo code***  :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
//loop through outer div
  $(".mec-bg-color ").each(function() {
  //use find to get text
    console.log($(this).find(".mec-event-loc-place").text());
    var text = $(this).find(".mec-event-loc-place").text().toLowerCase();
    var color = {
      'background-color': '#fff'
    };

    switch (text) {
      case "southern":
        color = "#ce1870";
        break;
      case "south eastern":
        color = "#6dc8bf";
        break;
    }
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event-grid-t2-head mec-bg-color clearfix">
  <div class="mec-event-month">
    <span class="mec-start-date-label" itemprop="startDate">28 September</span>
    <span class="mec-end-date-label" itemprop="endDate"> - 28 December</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mec-event-detail">
    <div class="mec-event-loc-place">Southern</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have the code now working.  The only issue I have now and wasn't expecting is the plugin has a Load More button and when this is pressed it loads the additional events but it doesn't format the colors.  I realize this is because the jQuery runs on the page load, so it might need to find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jQuery contains for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mec-event-loc-place:contains("southern")').css({'background-color':' #ce1870'});
  $('.mec-event-loc-place:contains("south eastern")').css({'background-color':'#6dc8bf'});
});
```

It would have pretty much the same effect with way less code.